# $Ajax request in codeigniter also check if request is correct

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have tried a lot and search a lot and i did the same as i see but i do not know where i am going wrong i am new to codeigniter. Can you please tell me where i am going wrong on the code ?  I want to set the product name in my input field according to the barcode selected. I am trying to fetch the product name and try to set it using AJAX but it is not working. Please you tell where is the bug in my code?

Here is my Controller Function in Main.php

```
 public function get_product()
    {   

        if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
           exit('No direct script access allowed');
        }
        $barcode = $_POST['barcode'];
        echo $barcode;
        exit;
        $data['result'] = $this->Item_model->get_product_using_barcode($barcode);
        print_r($data);
        exit;



    }
```

My Ajax Code  in js file :

```
$("#brcode").each(function(){

           $("#brcode").change(function(){

                    let value = $("#brcode").val();

                    $.ajax({
                            url: '<?php echo site_url("main/get_product"); ?>',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {'barcode': $('#brcode option:selected').val() },
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(data) {
                            //console.log(data);
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    })
           });

        });
```

Model Function :-

```
public function get_product_using_barcode($barcode){
         $query = $this->db->get_where('items',array('barcode' => $barcode));
         $result = $query->row();
         return $result;


     }
```

Please tell me where i am going wrong in my code?

Comment: You are requesting json but not returning json

Comment: try `json_encode($data);` to access response inside success callback function

Comment: I try to remove datatype:json from the request but  still not working ! if you can tell is my js is code is correct ?? do i am sending request to the correct function?

Comment: check your browser network tab? does the ajax request is going?

Comment: nope is it not showing any ajax request. did i make any mistake sending the ajax request in my js code?

Comment: $("#brcode").each(function(){   why do you used loop?

Comment: @PranaySute Please try my code and let me know if that helps you

Answer (score 2):

Try this code Its works for me. Hope this will help you.

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#brcode").change(function(){
        let value = $("#brcode").val();
        $.ajax({
                // URL should be include index.php
                url: '<?php echo site_url("index.php/main/get_product"); ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'barcode': $('#brcode option:selected').val() },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
                alert(data);
            }
        })
    });
 });
```

**Controller:**

```
public function get_product()
{   
    if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
       exit('No direct script access allowed');
    }
    $barcode = $_POST['barcode'];
    $data['result'] = $this->Item_model->get_product_using_barcode($barcode);
    return json_encode $data;
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function get_product_using_barcode($barcode){
     $query = $this->db->get_where('items',array('barcode' => $barcode));
     $result = $query->row();
     return $result;
 }
```

Greetings!

Comment: `<?php echo site_url("index.php/main/get_product"); ?>` No need of `index.php` here... as siteurl will automatically generate this.

Answer (score 1):

You are going wrong in this section as you are using `dataType: 'json'`, Your ajax should return a json object.

**PHP Tag won't work in js file, so you should put your ajax request either in footer of the page or hardcode your url. For example : `url:"http://localhost/retail/main/get_product"`**

Also i think `let value = $("#brcode").val();` should be `var value = $("#brcode").val();`

So your controller code should be

```
public function get_product()
{  
        $data = array();
        if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
           exit('No direct script access allowed');
        }
        $barcode = $_POST['barcode'];

        $data['result'] = $this->Item_model->get_product_using_barcode($barcode);
        echo json_encode(array("posted_data"=>$_POST,"database_data"=>$data['result']));
        exit;
}
```

And in success of ajax use this

```
 success: function(data) {
      console.log("Posted data");
      console.log(data.posted_data);
      console.log("Database data");
      console.log(data.database_data);
  }
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load url:"http://localhost/retail/main/get_product". Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.



It is not loading the url

Comment: @PranaySute Why are you doing cross origin are you not generating ajax request from same folder ?

Comment: I just want to set the name of the product depending on the barcode selected so i am trying to fetch the product name from the database but the url is showing the error in console i do not know what i am doing wrong in sending a request.

Comment: yup it is and i solved the issue i tried myself and the code work exactly the way i want but thanks @Praveen :) ..!!

Answer (score 1):

Can you change js code as like this. and try to see on console.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#brcode").change(function(){
                var value = $("#brcode").val();
                $.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo site_url("main/get_product"); ?>',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {'barcode': $('#brcode option:selected').val() },

                        success: function(data) {
                        //console.log(data);
                        alert(data);
                    }
                })
       });
 });
```

Comment: jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/retail/%3C?php%20echo%20site_url(%22main/get_product%22);%20?%3E 403 (Forbidden)


This error  i think something is wrong with sending the ajax request.

Comment: Hello i solved the issue and the ajax request is working now but can someone tell how can get a particular value from array object which i get in my response data???